# Remove ListView separator(in the xml layout file)

Tags: android, android-listview

How can I remove the rows separator in a `ListView`(if possible within the XML layout file where it's described)?

Answer (score 341):

Set the dividerHeight to zero and divider to null like this in xml:

```
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
android:divider="@null"
```

Or in java:

```
getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
getListView().setDivider(null);
```

Comment: setting null is enough, height setting is redundant

Comment: Yeap, with divider to null is enough.

Comment: I don't really understand where should I call getListView()?

Comment: @Neon - It's when you extend your Activity from ListActivity

See here - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html

Comment: If you use StickyListHeadersListView, you'll need both, setting to null won't be enough

Answer (score 79):

Simply put:

```
android:divider="@null"
```

Answer (score 44):

put below property in listview tag (in xml file)

```
android:divider="@null"
```

Answer (score 19):

You can set divider color as transparent color and divider height 
in 'ListView' properties to remove the divider like below:

```
android:divider="#00000000"  
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Comment: This was my first approach, but then I applied the above answer, put to divider to null.

Answer (score 16):

There are different ways to achieve this, but I'm not sure which one is the best (I don't even know is there is a best way). I know at least 2 different ways to do this in a ListView:

**1. Set divider to null:**

1.1. Programmatically

```
yourListView.setDivider(null);
```

1.2. XML

```
android:divider="@null" (this goes inside your ListView element)
```

**2. Set divider to transparent and set its height to 0 to avoid adding space between listview elements:**

2.1. Programmatically:

```
yourListView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));
yourListView.setDividerHeight(0);
```

2.2. XML

```
android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
```

Comment: Setting divider to null is obviously the best one, because it prevents any calculations being made by the system. The other is just a workaround.

Answer (score 6):

Only -1dp helps me to remove divider
(not 0, 0.0, @null or the same in code)

Android Studio, SDK L, android 4.2