# Android card view has thin gray line in between cards

Tags: android, android-xml

I have an android List view which shows card-like views, and as you can see in this picture, there is a thin gray line between my cards:

[image]

How can I get rid of the gray line?

My xml to achieve this card view is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_card">

    <!-- Card Contents go here -->

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beerNameList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Large Text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/beerBreweryNameList"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

bg_card.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
               android:dither="true">

            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>

            <solid android:color="#ccc" />

        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"
               android:dither="true">

            <corners android:radius="2dp" />

            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

            <padding android:bottom="8dp"
                     android:left="8dp"
                     android:right="8dp"
                     android:top="8dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Tried the change in the divider height, here is my code it did not get rid of the gray line:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/pbHeaderProgress"
            style="android@style/Spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="0px"
        >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: In Listview element set dividerHeight to 0dp and dividerColor to @android:color/transparent

Answer (score 16, accepted):

dividerHeight should work. As a workaround you could change the colour of divider to your background color or to transparent colour

```
<ListView 
 android:id="@+id/android:list"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:divider="#E6E6E6"
 android:dividerHeight="0px"/>
```

You can also try to this trick:

```
 android:divider="@null"
```

Answer (score 4):

I've just had the exact issue. Nothing from the XML was having effect on the outcome of the listview. Instead, as already mentioned in a comment by Quanturium, I went to my ListFragment's `onActivityCreated` and added -

```
getListView().setDivider(null);
getListView().setDividerHeight(0);
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using a listview, try setting this parameter in your listView `android:dividerHeight="0px"`

Comment: tried it and it didn't get rid of the line. I added the code in my question above.

Comment: @Mike http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081514/remove-listview-separatorin-the-xml-layout-file

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using a listview and this XML is the listitem. The gray line is the list divider. Set it to zero like this android:dividerHeight="0dp" for the listview.

Comment: didnt work, I also tried your answer and I still had gray lines.

Answer (score 0):

I need put

> dividierHeight = 0px

and chage color equal my backgroud color, in this case

> ```
> android:divider="#FFFFFF"
> ```

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/lv"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:dividerHeight="0px"
android:divider="#FFFFFF"
/>
```