# Gray horizontal line pre lollipop cardview on bottom

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am trying to get rid of this gray line on my cardview[image]
I am using a color with a bit of transparency - **#40B6F2FC**
here is my code

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:dividerHeight="0px"
        android:divider="@null"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/sky_colorBlue_20_percent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

Followed the answer of this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/18734605/1599611 but still didnt work.

Is there a way to get rid of this grayline without setting the elevation to zero and using a color with transparency added?

Answer (score 0):

Base from this tracker

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37008169

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior) CardView does not support
>   transparency for its background. This is due to limitations of drawing
>   shadows using canvas api.