# prominence of card view layout and divider color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-xml, android-cardview

I used CardView layout in `list_item.xml` "the xml post cell" for RecyclerView", I trying to making the cards prominenced and the color of divider close to gray like this

[image]

But it appears as like there is no emergence or color of it, 
this image for current situation

[image]

this **post_item.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postTitle"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="This is the post title,
you can check bla bla bla bla bla lkjdflkjhnfldkjhnflkjhnlfkjnglkjnlkjkln" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postDescription"
                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:text="This is the post titldfkjfdjffkjdhfnkjdsfjnkdsjnksskskjfnksjfnksjfnksjfnkjdfbdnfbjvb jkxzbvkjxcvbvkjve,
you can check bla bla bla bla bla lkjdflkjhnfldkjhnflkjhnlfkjnglkjnlkjkln" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/postImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="125dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I tried to solve the problem by adding this two lines on RecyclerView like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18734605/4205927) but it did not work 
`android:divider="#E6E6E6"
 android:dividerHeight="0px"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some searches, I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43406938/4205927) regarding the same issue

> The problem because this option was false in manifest file

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43407250/4205927) contains some choices that were very helpful to me like this

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

If issue still face issue use Background colour in RecycleView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardElevation="6dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    >
```

You must use:

```
app:cardElevation="6dp"
```

instead of:

```
android:elevation="6dp"
```

To draw shadow you must use hardwareAccelerated drawing

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

Explanation from Android doc :

> CardView adds additional padding to draw shadows on platforms before
>   L.
>
> This may cause Cards to have different sizes between L and before L.
>   If you need to align CardView with other Views, you may need api
>   version specific dimension resources to account for the changes. As an
>   alternative, you can set cardUseCompatPadding flag to true and
>   CardView will add the same padding values on platforms L and after.
>
> Since setting cardUseCompatPadding flag to true adds unnecessary gaps
>   in the UI, default value is false.

Answer (score 0):

After setting this options

```
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
app:cardElevation="6dp"
```

I suggest to add color off white color into RecyclerView

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#F5F5F5" // >>> this the color you need
        >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Comment: brilliant answer!,
this exactly What I needed